# App Engine's Vue PWA doesn't get updated on Custom domain

Tags: vue.js, google-app-engine, progressive-web-apps

When I upload Vue PWA on App Engine, GCP,

it does not get updated after the first deploy on custom domain, but it does on appspot.com

For example,

https://examplecustomdomain.com -> doesn't get updated

https://my-random-project.appspot.com -> does get updated

I assume the custom domain one is getting cached and not getting updated on new deployment.

I haven't touched anything about PWA setting so it should be set as default with vue cli.

What do I have to do to fix this?

Comment: 1. The [Mapping Custom Domain](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/mapping-custom-domains) worked before the last deploy?
2. The Custom domain is properly verified?
3. Did you make changes on the Custom Domains? or added [Wildcard mappings](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/mapping-custom-domains#wildcards)?

Comment: @JossBaron It seems the one I visited does not update. After I visited appspot one, it does not update until I hard refresh the cache...